# SQL Server 2005 Parse text into columns

Tags: sql, parsing, sql-server-2005, substring

I have text in columns that I want to parse out to multiple columns. The text is separated by `\`

Example 1 column:

```
alarmname
Rainier Beach (Henderson)\Tunnel Facility\C29_Facility\Offline - PLC 70
Rainier Beach (Henderson)\Tunnel Facility\C30_Facility\PLC DC Power 3 - Fault
```

I want to parse them into separate columns for each record. For example, for the first record above it would look like:

```
Rainier Beach (Henderson)
Tunnel Facility
C29_Facility
Offline - PLC 70
```

I can parse the first text value by using:

```
LEFT(alarmname,charindex('\',alarmname)-1)
```

which gives me:

```
Rainier Beach (Henderson)
```

But I don't know how to parse the second, third, fourth values...

Comment: Google "*SQL split function*".

Answer (score 0):

Try this link... it has a great Function you can use. All you need to do is add the function and then you call split('/', fieldname) and it works like a charm.

http://www.webtechminer.com/split-function-in-sql-server-to-break-comma-separated-string/

It returns a table.